# Using a passed variable to $_GET from database in $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what I am trying to do - I have a column that is `AUTO-INC` in the MySql table which is the `$job_numb`. I thought I could pass the variable along with the form action and pick it up in that form action file.

Here is the form action code:

```
 <form method="post" action="form_action2.php?attachment1=<?=$attachment1;?>, job_numb=<?=$job_numb;?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="due_date">Show Date</label><br>
           <input type="date" class="form-control" style="max-width: 200px;" id="show_date" name="show_date" value="<?php echo date("n/j/Y", strtotime("$show_date"))?>">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Update Record</button>
 </form>
```

Then I would like to use those variables to select the row in an UPDATE statement so I **a) can use the `$job_numb` to select the correct record** and **b) use BOTH for a `mail` action later in the script.**

I KNOW that `$_POST[]` and `$_GET[]` are two different functions, but this seems to make sense to me - how developers do this.

The script for `$_POST`:

```
 <?php
      echo($_GET['job_numb']);
      echo($_GET['attachment1']);

      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "XXXXXX";
      $password = "XXXXXX";
  try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=jobs_users", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     echo "Connected successfully";

      if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
            $job_numb = $_POST['job_numb'];
            $job_name = $_POST['job_name'];
            $job_name_clean = htmlspecialchars($job_name, ENT_QUOTES);
            $comments = $_POST['comments'];
            $comments_clean = htmlspecialchars($comments, ENT_QUOTES);
            $attachment2=$_POST['attachment2'];
            $due_date=$_POST['due_date'];
            $show_date=$_POST['show_date'];
            $AE=$_POST['AE'];
            $status=$_POST['status'];
            $assignee=$_POST['assignee'];
            $assign_email=$_POST['assign_email'];
            $property=$_POST['property'];
            }

      if(isset($_FILES['attachment2'])){
            $errors= array();
            $file_name = $_FILES['attachment2']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['attachment2']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['attachment2']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['attachment2']['type'];
            $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['attachment2']['name'])));

            $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","doc","pdf","docx","tif","tiff");

            if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
                  $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG, PNG, PDF, DOC, DOCX or TIF file.";
  }

  if ( ! $errors ) {
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
     echo $file_name;
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
    }

 $newdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($due_date));
 $showdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($show_date));
 $sql = "UPDATE `jobs_canjobs` SET `job_name`='$job_name_clean',`comments`='$comments_clean',`attachment2`='$file_name',`due_date`='$newdate', `show_date`='$showdate',`status`='$status',`assignee`='$assignee',`assign_email`='$assign_email',`AE`='$AE',`Property`='$property' WHERE job_numb = $job_numb";

  $conn->exec($sql);
     }
  catch(PDOException $e)
     {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
  $conn = null;
 ?>
```

I know the variables pass through to the execute file, but I am having trouble adding them to the whole action. AM I missing a step? Did I not do something correctly?

I would also like to point out that I am AWARE my code is choppy, I am aware that I am not using prepared statements. It will get better, and it is getting better - I read and I practice constantly. Thank you.

Comment: Use `&` and not `,` to seperate querystring varibales

Comment: And don't put a space between them, either.

Comment: @RiggsFolly okay thank you edited.

Comment: This is wrong on so many ways....how about using `hidden inputs` to store the values of `$attachment1` and the others and go full post?

Comment: @Hackerman I have it that way now, is that the only way? The `$attachment1` runs the risk of getting written over that way as well.

Comment: You can also build a client side `formData` and use `ajax` to post the information with `javascript`

Comment: I could, and I want to learn that as well.

Comment: Could I use this: [the $_REQUEST method](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: Dont edit fixes into your question. It makes the comments/answers you get look stupid. You can if you like answer your own question, so other can see the fixes easily

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to the top and was able to extract the `$url` string:

```
 $attachment1 = $_GET['attachment1'];
 $job_numb = $_GET['job_numb'];
```

I also had to edit the form action:

```
<form method="post" action="form_action2.php?attachment1=<?=$attachment1;?>&job_numb=<?=$job_numb;?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And that's it.

Comment: You forgot about my first comment about `&` and not `,` in the querystring

Comment: You want me to add that into my answer?